Use Ansible to copy entire directory into Docker container
I am successfully copying a single file with Ansible into my docker container with the following syntax:
- name: Copy SSH key into dev container
      community.docker.docker_container_copy_into:
        container: "{{ build_container_image_name }}"
        path: /tmp/build/ssh_keys/id_ed25519.pub
        container_path: /workspaces/project/keys/id_ed25519.pub
        mode: 0644
      become_user: "{{ builder_user }}"

However, I now also want to copy an entire directory into my Docker container with Ansible.
I cannot see a way to do this from the docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_copy_into_module.html
How can I use Ansible to copy an entire directory into the docker container?

Can you [edit] your question and give a bit more context on why you want to do this ? Because this is usually a pretty bad idea and there might be alternative ways to solve your root problem. See x/y problem. In any case, this module cannot copy directories.

Without any further context and information you'll probably left with looping over a list of files.
